# Can I open an account in Europe or Turkey ,being just as a tourist?

Tags: bank-account

is it possible for a foreigner, the person not residing there but can travel as a tourist,  to open an account in Europe or In middle east countries like Turkey or Dubai?

Answer (score 1):

Although countries like these abide by strict regulations, the truth is that it depends on what country you are a citizen of, and how much money you show up with.

Then the answer becomes "yes"